# How to get record in one table with conditional in two tables - PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table like

```
table: t1
id|name|type
1 | a  |0
2 | b  |1
3 | c  |0
4 | d  |0
...

table: t2
uid|type
4  |1
3  |0
...
```

I want to **count or get records in table t1** have type = 1 and records have id = uid in table t2 has type = 1 
What is the best way to count or get record in one query like

```
$type = 1;
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("Select * .... Where type = $type ")); //$count = 2
$result = mysql_query("Select * ... order by id desc "); // $result include record in table t1 has id (4, 2) b/c order by id desc
```

**Edit:**
i made a sql to try in **http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8847d1/12**
But i can't do that
I want the records result look like (all column have my above conditional)

```
id|name|
4 |d   | 
2 |b   |
```

How to do that thank

Comment: Are these tables linked i.e. have primary and foreign keys?

Comment: @jeff i doing direct, i don't using foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.id,t1.name from t1 left join t2 on t1.id = t2.uid where t1.type = 1 or t2.type = 1
```

Comment: result is 0 record. I think @jeff understand my question but his code don't work when i select * from t1 :|

Comment: As per your information in your tables you have id=3 and 4 in both your tables.So the on condition in the join is ok.But you dont have records with type = 1 in table1.So the and conditon in where will be changed to or.Then you will get records.

Comment: i change `and` to `or` in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8847d1/15. But results have one record. I want results like my edit question. Plz see my edit question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34509/discussion-between-user016-and-freestyle)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no link between the tables you can use a UNION query:

```
SELECT id,type FROM t1 WHERE type=1
UNION
SELECT uid AS id,type FROM t2 WHERE type=1
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html for more info on union joins.

Comment: i try to select all like: SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE type=1
UNION
SELECT uid AS id,type FROM t2 WHERE type=1 order by id desc .But it's not working :(

Comment: that's not working for select all plz see my code http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8847d1/12

Comment: The fields in both SELECT must match in the number of fields and the fieldnames themselves that is why the 'uid as id' in the second select statement

Comment: Use the sqlFiddle file and copy my answer into where you have your sql statement.

Comment: yeah i done with another way here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8847d1/46. what about that? thank :)

Comment: If it works for you then that's ok. If you follow the 2 simple rules: each select statement must match in the number of fields and the fieldnames then it would make your statement a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.uid where t1.type = 1 and t2.type = 1
```

read how to use join(left join,right join,join)

[1. read here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)

[2. 2nd docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: i think u don't understand my question. I do your code but have not record if table t1 don't have type = 1; :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$type = 1;
if ( isset($type) and $type > 0 )
{
    $sql =  "SELECT id, name FROM t1
            LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.uid
            WHERE t1.type = $type AND t2.type = $type 
            ORDER BY t1.id DESC";
    $count  = mysql_num_rows( $sql ) or die('Error');
    $result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die('Error');
}
```